# Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, code-signing, xcode15, macos-sonoma

[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLmRD.png) [help me out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR0cF.png) As soon as Updated to the latest Xcode 15, I started getting this error.

I also Updated my mac to sonoma os .I have been stuck on this error for 3 days now and tried everything.

Flutter Code was working fine over Xcode 14.

Pod update
pod install
pod degenerated and installed again
The IOS folder was deleted and then made again using Flutter Create.

Noting Works Help me here.

Comment: Can you modify your podfile, if needed?

Comment: cant we, we tend to modify the file when we need in flutter applications. Can you tell me if there is any solution to this?

Comment: Please add error messages as text instead of images.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This worked for me**

```
xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

  post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        # For xcode 15+ only
         if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
           File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This answer in 90% simlilar to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77242735/1974224). Please give appropriate cred it that answer was a source of inspiration for yours.

Comment: Thanks @Cristik for being so generous.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your podfile:

```js
xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        # For xcode 15+ only
         if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
           File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

If you already have a `post_install do |installer|`, add only the `if` condition along with the `end`.

Comment: Sure i will check it  and then update you.

Comment: I have started getting this error now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wlFZ_2zIBRE2aqi7gfGDoJuFa8bQNZoL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: help me out here

Comment: Try updating the cocoapods using:  sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: your answer was a source of inspiration for me to reach the correct answer.

Comment: Glad to know that bro. Thanks :)

Comment: Also you can mark your answer as correct so that no one gets confused between the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error after upgrading to Mac OS Sonoma. After trying dozens of tricks, I uninstalled everything and tried to delete all the hidden files. Then I reinstalled Xcode, Flutter and Visual Studio Code, following precisely the guide on the Flutter site. It worked for me.