xcode 15 Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
I updated my xcode to 15.4
Im running flutter run on iphone 15 pro simulator
pod --version is 1.15.2
In my PodFile I added
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end

the error I see
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code


Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77242735/833395

I tried that and it gives me
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found /Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-3.3.0/ios/Classes/FWFWebViewFlutterWKWebViewExternalAPI.h:4:8 

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/833395

None of the solutions above solved my problem. What happened was that when I upgraded my Mac and Xcode versions, the Flutter project folder on my desktop was saved to iCloud Drive. Disabling the sync with iCloud solved the problem, and all the errors disappeared.

Just disable the icloud sync with your flutter project it will solve your problem
System Setting -> Apple Account (1st item from list) -> icloud -> Disable Desktop and Documents

